# How to get best performance to handle connection in http requests?

Tags: rest, websocket, undertow, thorntail

We have Enterprise application in J2EE platform in `thorntail` to massive restful request, my question is clients should open and close connection for each request? or not? , can we use persist connection and handle request with WebSocket? what is best practice to improve performance?
**Update:**
In this case we provide REST API for Clients that has not browser web interface, and send many http request in TPS-3000

Comment: Without a concrete use case and usage scenario (how many connections are we talking about), this is impossible to answer. Also it is not clear whether you are just asking for a general advice (best practice) or if you already have issues or bottlenecks.

Comment: Indeed it's not possible to give an advice for such general question, but there's one important thing to note: Thorntail is actually WildFly under the hood, so any performance tuning that applies to WildFly will apply to Thorntail as well.

Comment: I have updated post, we are looking for general arch solution in this case